# Eigenvalues of differentiable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a real-valued matrix, $M(a)$, which is a differentiable function of $a$, but not continuously differentiable, with $M(0)=I$. I'll assume $M'(0)$ has distinct eigenvalues.

I'm looking for results proving the differentiability of the eigenvalues of $M(0)$.  I suspect it may be a challenging proof because when I read the literature, I see people making very restrictive assumptions, usually that the eigenvalues are distinct (clearly not true for me), and if not, it seems that people assume the matrix is symmetric, also not true for me.

If I assume the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are differentiable, say with $v_1(a)$ being one of the eigenvectors, then I believe I can conclude that $v_1(0)$ is an eigenvector of $M'(0)$ and I can work out $\lambda_1'(0)$.  If so I've got the result I'm trying to prove.

Is it known whether the eigenvalues of a differentiable real matrix are in fact differentiable, even if repeated?  If true - where can I find a reference?  If false, where can I found a counterexample?  If unknown - what's the challenge in proving it?

Comment: The challenge with repeated eigenvalues (at first glance at least) seems to be in deciding which path a *particular* eigenvalue takes when eigenvalues come together and go apart as $a$ increases. Symmetric matrices make things *much* easier because the eigenvalues are real and the Courant-Fischer (min/max) theorem applies.

Comment: Not an expert, but I think the definitive reference on using analytic methods to deal with matrices is Matrix Analysis by Horn and Johnson

Comment: Bhatia's Matrix analysis has a lot in the way of this *kind* of thing, but I don't remember if he handles the repeated case.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom So if I can take the first order approximation for my case $I+aB$, it's pretty straightforward to figure out what the path is for a particular eigenvalue/eigenvector is (it's the eigenvectors for $B$ and $1+a\lambda_B$ for the eigenvalues.  So I expect this to hold generally with $M(0)=I$.  But I'm not sure I can assume even continuity of $M'(a)$, so...

Comment: This is a nasty problem since as a function of $a$ eigenvalues may cross. This is a familiar situation in quantum chemistry when the eigenvalues of a diatomic molecule are studied. Sometimes they do not cross, so-called avoided crossings, see von Neumann's non-crossing rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avoided_crossing

Comment: A further complication is that $M(a)$ and $M(b)$ may not commute for $a≠b$. Have a look at Kato's "Perturbation theory of linear operators" where he formulates matters in terms of complex contour integrals.  Note: in the above comment about diatomic molecules I mean as a function of interatomic distance.

Comment: What an interesting problem ! Intuitively, since the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial change smoothly with $a$, one would expect the roots of that polynomial also to change smoothly. They might pop into and out of the real line, but as complex numbers they should follow smooth curves. I guess these are the paths you guys are discussing, when you mention the problem of eigenvalues coalescing and separating ?

Comment: @Simon Yes, I have seen work in this direction. In fact there is quite some (mathematical-physical) literature on this subject. A good start is Chapter Two, Perturbation theory in a finite-dimensional space, in the book by Kato to which I refered earlier.